# Check all strings in arraylist contains in other arraylist

Tags: c#

I trying make if Arraylist all values contains in other arraylist (all values)

Arraylist one:

```
Name
Item
```

ArrayList two:

```
Item
Name
Count
```

Note: the lists are shuffled

I tried this:

```
foreach (string str1 in arraylistone)
                            {
                                if (arraylisttwo.Contains(str1))
                                {
                                    //return true;
                                }
                            }
```

But it says true if contains someone element

Comment: Use `List<string>`. Don't use `ArrayList` unless you enjoy making your life harder...

Comment: I Could have not made a better statement. Thanks  @elgonzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to skin a cat. Here is one using Linq's `Join` extension method:

```
var list1 = new[] { "Name",  "Item" };
var list2 = new[] { "Item", "Name", "Count" };
var join = list1.Join(list2, l1 => l1, l2 => l2, (l1, l2) => new { l1, l2 });
var allContained = join.Count() == list1.Count();
```

Just be careful with comparison of strings. There is an overload that takes an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` to allow you to define how the keys are compared.

**Update:**

As Alex Leo has pointed out, you can use `Intersect`:

```
 var allContained = list1.Intersect(list2).Count() == list1.Count();
```

Much simpler and it also provides an `IEqualityComparer<T>` overload.

Comment: How can I get Join from Linq?

Comment: @Slinidy: Add a using statement at the top: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I added and not working my arraylist:         public ArrayList arraylistone = new ArrayList();

Comment: You need to cast your `ArrayList` to an `Array` first: `arraylistone.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Enumerable.Intersect.

```
        var listA = new List<string> { "Name", "Item" };
        var listB = new List<string> { "Name", "Item","Count" };

        var c = listA.Intersect(listB).ToList();
```

Comment: There is no method for Intersect

Comment: you need the using System.Linq; statement

Comment: I added and not working my arraylist: public ArrayList arraylistone = new ArrayList();

Comment: ArrayList doesn't have .Intersect method. What we are suggesting  is to use a List<T>  System.Collections.Generic;

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
var arrayOne = new string[4];
    arrayOne[0] = "Item1";
    arrayOne[1] = "Item2";
    arrayOne[2] = "Item3";
    arrayOne[3] = "Item4";

var arrayTwo = new string[4];
    arrayTwo[0] = "Item1";
    arrayTwo[1] = "Item2";
    arrayTwo[2] = "Item3";
    arrayTwo[3] = "Item4";

    var allItemIsThere = true;

    foreach (var one in arrayOne)
    {
        allItemIsThere = arrayTwo.Contains(one);
        if(!allItemIsThere)
        { break;}
    }
```